# Backup of images that aren't in the repository

Tags: file, svn, backup, restore

I have the code of a website in a subversion repository.
The admin of the site can upload images via a CMS.
These images go to different directories inside "`webroot/uploads/`".
This directory forms part of the repository, too.

I have a cron task to backup periodically (via svnadmin dump) the repository, but the images uploaded by the user aren't in the backup because they aren't in the repository.

At this moment only the admin of the CMS can upload images and not any other user of the web.

I'm thinking about doing a backup of "`webroot/uploads/*`" with tar and gzip.
A different idea is to somehow include automatically the uploaded images into the repository.
One more advantage of this is that I will receive in my development computer all the images when I update the repository.

What do you think is the best way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, binary contents (exe, dll, images, ...) which don't benefit from version control features (diff, labels, merges, ...) aren't under version control.

However:

- if those images doesn't change much (ie the same image doesn't get modified over and over), and
- if their number is limited (ie you don't upload `to webroot/uploads/*` thousands of images a day)

, you can consider adding them to your SVN repo (since it is a *centralized* repo, you don't have the worry of cloning the full history of a repo like for a DVCS).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, VonC. Sure the images aren't thousands per day. Now the question is how. The admin uploads the image and a process in PHP stores it, creating a directory if necessary, it depends on the kind of content the image belongs to. How I can "commit" the new image/s and directory (if it's created) automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: And one more question (this one almost a philosophical one): What's the need of store them in the repository if the user will never roll back to a previous version? He/she just will upload another image to change the current one.

The admin is a user who has no clue about subversion or even a shell.

Comment: @Víctor: you just laid out an argument *against* putting those images under source control ;) But should you still want them in a repo, then that would mean a job on your side monitoring the server (and what has been uploaded), rsync any updated/new files from the server back to your local repo, where you have the control and can commit at any time.

Comment: After thinking about the pros and cons I have decide to exclude the images that aren't related to the look & feel of the website from the repository and backup them apart from the repository via tar & gzip. Thank you VonC for your insight that helped me to have more facts in order to decide.